# Posting from Drupal to WordPress

Tags: 7

Basically I'm looking for a module/tool/mechanism that I could use to post to a WordPress install from my Drupal install. Ideally this would be filtered per post type and on/off per post. My scenario. I've got a custom post type in my Drupal site which I post to frequently. Sometimes (depending on the post) I'd like to to post to WordPress also, without the hassle of having to login to another platform. Apparently there was this module: https://drupal.org/project/wp_publish

But it seems is not ported to D7. Any knows anything else?

Many thanks

PS: Its not a migration. Some posts will only go to D7, and some will be posted on D7 and WP.
PPS: Both sites have very different objectives and only share some content, so no need for a joint solution/migration/etc.

Comment: That module was never developed, even for D6. It is an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

Now nothing about wp, but in drupal you will have to fire the event when the node is saved and your form field,  "save into wp" is active.

Basically I'd do this with hook node api. Use case "save", check then the field and then fire the function or api which allows you to save the content into wp

Comment: I haven't really used the hook api nor hooks in general and I'm not sure this particularly need is worth the trouble. I might do something if have spare time, but was wondering whether there was something available already. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have is actually the other way around. For the Dupal only articles you should post to Drupal but for the Wordpress and Drupal articles, post those to Wordpress, you should allow wordpress to create an RSS feed then Drupal can consume that feed and create content on the Drupal site automagically using the feeds module

Comment: its an idea, however not ideal as the workflow is drupal->wordpress. I rarely post on wp and that would remediate that. Anyway, something to keep in mind. Thanks anyway.